# FB.logout() not working with angular/ionic 3

Tags: javascript, java, facebook, api

I have an Ionic 3 application that will be a pwa.
I'm using the javascript facebook API to login to the app.

It logs in and brings the user information, but when I call FB.logout () it just changes the status of connected to unknow and does not logout facebook is still open in the browser.
What alternative could I use to leave facebook?

I need it to log out so that another user wants to sign in with facebook.

[google chrome console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHe96.png)

Comment: Did the user log in to Facebook to be able to login to your app to begin with? If they were logged in to Facebook before already, then you can not log them out of Facebook from within your app.

Comment: was not logged in, login is done in the application when calling `FB.login ()`, but because it is an Ionic app and being tested in Chrome, it opens facebook in chrome, when it is built for PWA it will behave like that too?

Comment: Don’t know; but - where’s this PWA supposed to run anyway, not on a user’s mobile device? Because in that scenario, there should be rather little need for “user switching” in general; and if someone actually needs this once in a while, they might have to go and log out of Facebook manually then.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in the Graph API logout method. I used the angularx-social-login package instead of my own implementation because I realized that logout worked on it. The package use Graph API version 2.9. Due to another need that arose in the project, I created a new service using the latest API version, which is version 4.0, and FB.logout () is working normally. The problems apparently was in version 3.2